# pass parameter from one IBAction to another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibaction

The code below displays a random word from an array (generateWord), and then accepts a letter as input, based on which button was pressed. I would like, in letterGuessed, to be able to search for the input letter within the contents of the randomWord variable. I know how I would search, but I cannot access the variable. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
- (IBAction)generateWord:(id)sender {
    int arraycount=[wordList count];
    int indexchoice=(arc4random() % arraycount);
    NSString *randomWord = [wordList objectAtIndex:indexchoice];
    self.wordResult.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"word: %@ ",randomWord];
}

- (IBAction)letterGuessed:(id)sender {
    NSString *letter=[sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setEnabled:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You make "NSString *randomWord" an ivar, so in "generateWord:" you set randonWord (i.e. "randomWord = [wordList objectAtIndex:indexchoice];"), then randomWord is now available when "letterGuessed:" is invoked.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Does it have to do with declaring the variable '@public'?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways..

1)Have a global copy of the randomVariable and update it every time generateWord is clicked..

2)Or You can circumvent the above approach by simply getting the string contents from wordResult textview/textfield u have created

```
 NSString *randomString = self.wordResult.text
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, aren't global variables frowned upon in OOP? I'm new to this but I thought I read it somewhere.

Comment: not necessarily.. as long as it serves a significant purpose you can use Global variables..